# How can i get a dropdown for a CharField in Wagtail Admin?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

In Django Admin, it is possible to add a dropdown selector with all possible enum values like this example:

```
class ThesisStatus(models.TextChoices):
    OPEN = 'O', _('Offen')
    TAKEN = 'T', _('Vergeben')
    WORK_IN_PROGRESS = 'W', _('In Arbeit')
    COMPLETED = 'C', _('Komplett')
    ABORTED = 'A', _('Abgebrochen')

status = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=ThesisStatus.choices,
    default=ThesisStatus.OPEN,
)
```

In wagtail, this does not work:

```
panels = [
   FieldPanel('status'),
]
```

if the field is a `CharField`, but it does work for a `TextField`. How can I fix or implement this for `CharField`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code above works fine when using `CharField` so I have assumed you want to get this working with `TextField` instead.

When defining a Django model's field, each field comes with a default widget, `CharField` has some smarter handling for when `choices` is provided to the field and uses the `Select` widget.

However, the [`TextField`'s default widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) is the `TextArea` so you need to provide Wagtail with the widget you want to use.

Widgets are a Django term for how to present the field as a HTML field, the [`Select` widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#select) is what you want to use for a drop-down but there are many other build in widgets.

Finally, to tell Wagtail what widget to use for the [`FieldPanel` you need to pass in a `widget` kwarg](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html#fieldpanel).

After this, you should see that the UI will show a select drop down but will be stored as a `TextField` in the database.

##### Example: **models.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.db import models

class MyPage(Page):
    # ... other fields

    class ThesisStatus(models.TextChoices):
        OPEN = "O", "Offen"
        TAKEN = "T", "Vergeben"
        WORK_IN_PROGRESS = "W", "In Arbeit"
        COMPLETED = "C", "Komplett"
        ABORTED = "A", "Abgebrochen"
    
    # note: using `models.TextField` here
    status = models.TextField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=ThesisStatus.choices,
        default=ThesisStatus.OPEN,
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("status", widget=forms.Select), # note: using widget here
        # ... other panels
        ]
```

##### Docs Links

- [Django Fields (Choices)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices)
- [Django Fields (TextField)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)
- [Django Widgets (Select)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#select)
- [Wagtail FieldPanel](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html#fieldpanel)